# Cannot create channel field

Tags: ee2, custom-fields, mysql

After upgrading to EE 2.6.1, i now try to create a new channel field, but instead get this SQL error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY `screen_name`, `username` ASC' at line 4
SELECT `member_id`, `group_id`, `username`, `screen_name` FROM (`exp_members`) WHERE `in_authorlist` = 'y' OR `group_id` IN () ORDER BY `screen_name`, `username` ASC

Filename: fieldtypes/relationship/libraries/Relationships_ft_cp.php
Line Number: 163
```

Anyboy knows how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that no member group is selected as "Include Members in PUBLISH page multi-author list?". Go to Control Panel -> Members -> Member Groups. Click on "Edit Group" next to Super Admin. Now make sure the "Include Members in PUBLISH page multi-author list?" is "Yes".

Comment: AH, neve would have thought of that.. Thanks a lot!